# How to show application version in environment view?

Tags: deployment, gitlab-ci, versioning

I use GitLab to build and deploy my Java application. The version of my application is saved in the Maven POM file.

After deploying the deployment is shown in the environment view, see  [Environments and deployments](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments/). But the version is not displayed in the view.

**Pipeline**

```yaml
stages:     
  - build
  - deploy

build-job:      
  stage: build
  image: maven:3.6.3-jdk-11
  script:
    - mvn package

deploy-job:     
  stage: deploy  
  environment: production
  script:
  - | 
    VERSION=`mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout`
    echo "Deploying application with $VERSION..."
```

**Environment view**

[image: environment view]

**Research**

- I looked into the [.gitlab-ci.yml keyword reference](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#environment), but I couldn't find a way to show the application version in the view.
- I looked into the [Predefined variables reference](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html), but I couldn't find a way to show the application version in the view.
- I could click on the branch link, navigate to the POM file and open it, but I would see only the current version not the deployed version.
- I could click on the commit SHA link, navigate to the POM file and open it, but this way is error-prone.
- I could click on the job link and read the log file, but this way is not quick and convenient.

**Question**

Is there any way to show the application version in the enviroment view?

Comment: Why is clicking on the commit SHA error prone?

Comment: By "the view", do you mean GitLab web UI?

Comment: @RaglandAsir *Why is clicking on the commit SHA error prone?* If you click on it, you need to navigate to the file containing the version. It is not shown directly. If you navigate the wrong way, you are seeing the file on the main branch.

Comment: @RaglandAsir Yes, I want to see the version in Gitlab web UI. Is there any way?